# $\begin{cases} T(1) = 1 \quad \quad \quad \\ T(n) = 4T(n-1) + 3 \end{cases}$ using method of summation factors?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations, recursion

I need to calculate the following recurrence relation (I know how, below is explanation) using method of summation factors:

$\begin{cases} T(0) = 1  \\ T(n) = 4T(n-1) + 3 \end{cases}$

Brief definition of method of summation factors:

> Let there be given recursive formula:
>
> $$a_{n}T_{n} = b_{n}T_{n-1} + c_{n}$$
>
> where:
>
> $$a_{n} \neq 0 \iff n \geq 0$$ $$b_{n} \neq 0 \iff n > 0$$
>
> then the solution $T_{n}$ of the recursive formula is defined as:
>
> $$T_{n} = \frac{1}{S_{n}a_{n}}(S_{1}b_{1}T_{0} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n} S_{k}c_{k})$$
>
> where:
>
> $$S_{n} = \frac{a_{1}a_{2}...a_{n-2}a_{n-1}}{b_{2}b_{3}...b_{n-1}b_{n}} \quad \quad \land \quad \quad S_{1} = 1$$

$\begin{cases} T(0) = 1  \\ T(n) = 4T(n-1) + 3 \end{cases}$

Here $a_{n} = 1, b_{n} = 4, c_{n} = 3$

So $S_{n} = \frac{1^{n-1}}{4^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{4^{n-1}}$

Plugging into formula:

$$T(n) = 4^{n-1} \Bigg( 1*4*1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Big( \frac{1}{4^{k-1}} * 3 \Big)  \Bigg)$$

The above calculations are correct and after simplification WolframAlpha yielded correct result. Wolfram code:

`4^(n-1) * (4 + sum from k = 1 to n of (3/(4^(k-1)))`

WolframAlpha's simplified result is

$$T(n) = 2^{2n+1} - 1$$

which yields: $7, 31, 127, 511, 2047$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ respectively, which are all correct.

---

**My problem is:** I know how to solve such relations using this method (I need to use this method, not my choice).

But what if there was $T(1) = 1$ as a stop condition instead of $T(0) = 1$?

So the relation would be of the form:

$$\begin{cases} T(1) = 1 \\ T(n) = 4T(n-1) + 3 \end{cases}$$

I expect $T(n) = 2^{2n - 1} - 1$ as a closed-form final answer, which yields $1, 7, 31, 127, 511$ for $n \in [1, 5]$

I am just not sure what should I do differently when dealing with the calculations, in order to obtain that result.

Comment: It's just a change of variable! Set $U(n)=T(n+1)$ and solve $U$ with your I-am-forbidden-from-using-my-brain-and-have-to-apply-this-exact-method to $U$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: This works. Thanks. Once I obtain the closed-form result $U(n) = f(n)$, I plug-back $T(n)$ in such a manner: $T(n) = f(n - 1)$ I suppose. Seems to work.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: If you wish, do feel free to post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

Let $T(m)=U(m)+a$

$$3=T(n)-4T(n-1)=U(n)-4U(n-1)-3a$$

WLOG set $a=-1,$

$T(m)=U(m)-1,$

$1=T(0)=U(0)-1\implies U(0)=2$

to find $$U(n)=4U(n-1)=4^rU(n-r)=4^nU(0)=2\cdot4^n=2^{1+2n}$$